# Is this inter-thread object sharing strategy sound?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-memory

I'm trying to come up with a fast way of solving the following problem:

I have a thread which produces data, and several threads which consume it. I don't need to queue produced data, because data is produced much more slowly than it is consumed (and even if this failed to be the case occasionally, it wouldn't be a problem if a data point were skipped occasionally). So, basically, I have an object that encapsulates the "most recent state", which only the producer thread is allowed to update.

My strategy is as follows (please let me know if I'm completely off my rocker):

I've created three classes for this example: `Thing` (the actual state object), `SharedObject<Thing>` (an object that can be local to each thread, and gives that thread access to the underlying Thing), and `SharedObjectManager<Thing>`, which wraps up a `shared_ptr` along with a `mutex`.

The instance of the `SharedObjectManager` (SOM) is a global variable.
When the producer starts, it instantiates a Thing, and tells the global SOM about it. It then makes a copy, and does all of it's updating work on that copy. When it is ready to commit it's changes to the Thing, it passes the new Thing to the global SOM, which locks it's mutex, updates the shared pointer it keeps, and then releases the lock.

Meanwhile, the consumer threads all intsantiate `SharedObject<Thing>`. these objects each keep a pointer to the global SOM, as well as a cached copy of the `shared_ptr` kept by the SOM... It keeps this cached until `update()` is explicitly called.

I believe this is getting hard to follow, so here's some code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Thing
{
    private:
        int _some_member = 10;
    public:
        int some_member() const { return _some_member; }
        void some_member(int val) {_some_member = val; }
};

// one global instance
template<typename T>
class SharedObjectManager
{
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<T> objPtr;
        std::mutex objLock;

    public:
        std::shared_ptr<T> get_sptr()
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(objLock);
            return objPtr;
        }

        void commit_new_object(std::shared_ptr<T> new_object)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (objLock);
            objPtr = new_object;
        }
};


// one instance per consumer thread.
template<typename T>
class SharedObject
{
    private:
        SharedObjectManager<T> * som;
        std::shared_ptr<T> cache;

    public:
        SharedObject(SharedObjectManager<T> * backend) : som(backend)
        {update();}

        void update()
        {
            cache = som->get_sptr();
        }

        T & operator *()
        {
            return *cache;
        }

        T * operator->()
        {
            return cache.get();
        }


};



// no actual threads in this test, just a quick sanity check.

SharedObjectManager<Thing> glbSOM;

int main(void)
{
    glbSOM.commit_new_object(std::make_shared<Thing>());

    SharedObject<Thing> myobj(&glbSOM);

    std::cout<<myobj->some_member()<<std::endl;
    // prints "10".
}
```

The idea for use by the producer thread is:

```
// initialization - on startup
auto firstStateObj = std::make_shared<Thing>();
glbSOM.commit_new_object(firstStateObj);

// main loop
while (1)
{
    // invoke copy constructor to copy the current live Thing object
    auto nextState = std::make_shared<Thing>(*(glbSOM.get_sptr()));

    // do stuff to nextState, gradually filling out it's new value 
    //    based on incoming data from other sources, etc.
    ...

    // commit the changes to the shared memory location
    glbSOM.commit_new_object(nextState);
}
```

The use by consumers would be:

```
SharedObject<Thing> thing(&glbSOM);
while(1)
{
    // think about the data contained in thing, and act accordingly...
    doStuffWith(thing->some_member());        

    // re-cache the thing
    thing.update();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<T> objPtr;` has me in fear that somewhere out there there is another party using `*objPtr` without appropriate protections. Afraid I have to say no.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Instead use a queue in the producer of limited size holding only valid (committed) objects and  allowing dropping elements. That might be simpler (getting rid of a useless manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is way overengineered. Instead, I'd suggest to do following:

- Create a pointer to `Thing* theThing` together with protection mutex. Either a global one, or shared by some other means. Initialize it to nullptr.
- In your producer: use two local objects of `Thing` type - `Thing thingOne` and `Thing thingTwo` (remember, `thingOne` is no better than `thingTwo`, but one is called `thingOne` for a reason, but this is a thing thing. Watch out for cats.). Start with populating `thingOne`. When done, lock the mutex, copy `thingOne` address to `theThing`, unlock the mutex. Start populating `thingTwo`. When done, see above. Repeat untill killed.
- In every listener: (make sure the pointer is not nullptr). Lock the mutex. Make a copy of the object pointed two by the `theThing`. Unlock the mutex. Work with your copy. Burn after reading. Repeat untill killed.

Comment: Definitely watch out for cats. He wants all your base.

Comment: @user4581301, one of us didn't get the joke. Who would it be?

Comment: If copying the object is for some reason a problem, you can use a `shared_ptr<Thing const>` protected by a mutex. Or if only one thread ever needs to consume the object, you can use a `unique_ptr<Thing>` that you move in/out under protection of a mutex.

Comment: Not sure @SergeyA . Possibly one of the two fish. I'm guessing the red one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the object should be either copied or moved, otherwise, the design falls apart.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks, this is a good suggestion. Since I'm going to have a lot of these channels, I'm still going to wrap the mutex and pointer in an object, but the whole thing can be much simpler as you suggest. I have an updated copy of the code - where should I post it? Extend the original question? Overwrite it? A new "answer"? What's the stackoverflow protocol on such follow-ups?

Comment: @HarrisMSnyder, what exactly do you want with new code? Why do you need it posted?

Comment: @SergeyA just wanted another set of eyes on the implementation, that's the main reason for the question overall.